# Otp enrichment for dynamic link - No language specific

Tags: security, authentication, dynamic, access-token, one-time-password

for my website i do generate one time password using token hardware time based (no keypad).

The new requirement is to generate and accept a code linked to transaction amount.

In order to do this using the same hardware tokens, can i enrich otp accepted asking to insert some digits ?

For example for a transaction of 192$ and otp generated value "123456", the server tells: "add 2 digits of the amount on top" and the user has to insert the value 19123456.

The other time for example if the transaction is of 4$ and the otp generated value is "456456" the server could tell "add 3 digits of the amount in the end" and the user has to insert the value "456456004"

Is it secure/safe?

Does it exist something similar?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to use the same token - this could be a trick, an amount will be protected. But what if someone will change the currency or receiver of the payment?

For a better security, I suggest considering OCRA (RFC 6287) algorithm, which is designed for generating OTPs based on transaction data.

The benefit of such approach is that much more data could be involved in OTP generating and protected from hacking in this way. In the same time, a user still receives the code of the same length.

There are a lot of options in protecting transactions' data, like CWYS (Confirm What You See) and other, with software and hardware tokens.